# MYSQL UPDATE for same id

Tags: mysql, sql

IMPLEMENTATION: A buyer purchase a product and after it paid the product it will transfer to the seller balance.
PROBLEM: total.seller has id of 1,1,2 but it only manage to update 1,2 only and disregard the other 1 id. Any solution for this? to update same id

```
UPDATE tbclientdetails cd2
JOIN(
SELECT  cd.client_id, cd.money_balance AS buyerbalance, lp.sellerid AS seller, lp.product_price AS price
FROM tbclientlogin cl
LEFT JOIN tbclientdetails cd ON cd.client_id = cl.client_login_id
LEFT JOIN tbclientrole cr ON cr.client_role_id = cd.role
LEFT JOIN tbpurchasedetails pd ON pd.client_purchase_id =cd.client_id
LEFT JOIN tbpaymentstatus ps ON ps.status_id = pd.payment_status
LEFT JOIN tblazardoproduct lp ON lp.product_id = pd.client_product_purchase_id
WHERE ps.status_option = "UNPAID" AND cd.client_email = "justin@gmail.com" AND cr.client_role_type = "BUYER"
) total
SET cd2.money_balance = total.price
WHERE cd2.client_id = total.seller
```

Comment: Please re-read [How do I ask a question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), because we cannot see/know/smell what you are doing.  Some sample data, and desired output might help to understand what you are doing/seeing/....

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to join the single purchase rows, because then one table rows get several updates and the last one wins. You want *one* update per client with the `SUM` of the related unpaid purchases.

```
UPDATE tbclientdetails cd2
JOIN(
  SELECT lp.sellerid AS seller, SUM(lp.product_price) AS price
  FROM tbclientlogin cl
  LEFT JOIN tbclientdetails cd ON cd.client_id = cl.client_login_id
  LEFT JOIN tbclientrole cr ON cr.client_role_id = cd.role
  LEFT JOIN tbpurchasedetails pd ON pd.client_purchase_id =cd.client_id
  LEFT JOIN tbpaymentstatus ps ON ps.status_id = pd.payment_status
  LEFT JOIN tblazardoproduct lp ON lp.product_id = pd.client_product_purchase_id
  WHERE ps.status_option = 'UNPAID'
    AND cd.client_email = 'justin@gmail.com'
    AND cr.client_role_type = 'BUYER'
  GROUP BY lp.sellerid
) total
SET cd2.money_balance = total.price
WHERE cd2.client_id = total.seller;
```

I am not sure about the rest. The client is the seller? And the balance is the sum of unpaid product prices? This may or may not be correct. I just copied it from your query. Also, I am not sure whether all the IDs are correctly stated. I just took what you showed us. Maybe you want to try the subquery as a standalone query first to see whether it gets yu what you expect.

At last: Your outer joins don't work. If there is a cl without a cd, then the outer joined row has nulls for all cd columns. `WHERE cd.client_email = 'justin@gmail.com'` dismisses hence all outer joined rows and you remain with a mere inner join. You should correct this by either moving the criteria to the `ON` clause to get the outer join working or by making the inner join explicit with `INNER JOIN` instead of `LEFT [OUTER] JOIN`.

By the way: string literals get quoted with single quotes in SQL. Double quotes are for names. Confusing the two can sometimes lead to unexpected results.